# Why doesn't Stack Overflow allow discussable questions or questions that require opinions?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

Why doesn't Stack Overflow welcome discussable questions or questions that require opinions?

I think these types of questions may also be beneficial like the coding questions.

Comment: They are absolutely valid questions or exchanges of information. They just fit poorly into the Q&A format. To keep quality high, you will have to disallow certain things.

Comment: Because they *don't fit the format*. A discussion is a two-way street, an ongoing conversation. There is no room for that on Stack Overflow. Take that elsewhere instead.

Comment: You may want to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com) instead.

Comment: Cross-site related: [The fourth place: Polling, Recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-stuff)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because such questions are less likely to reach any conclusion or solution!

Stack Overflow is meant for providing solutions to realtime problems but not the never ending discussions.

Questions like "Is Java better than C#?" or "Which is the best programming language?" are only a burden to the site, and not helpful to any extent what Stack Overflow is meant for.

Comment: Any suggestion on what **would** be an appropriate place to ask them then?

Comment: IMO, this kind of question could actually be useful, even without a best answer. The problem, of course, is that SO does not fit this kind of thing because one answer must be chosen and people are competing for points. It's a pity SO does not have an old-fashioned forum, but maybe, this gamification thing is exactly the reason why SO tech answers are superior than the competition

Comment: @Leo you have chat.stackoverflow.com for that..

Comment: @InfantPro'Aravind' but the chat is not stored anywhere, is it? Many good answers in SO just have several answers, each one presenting some point of view and no "best answer" chosen.

Comment: @Noctis If you were to ask something along the lines of "For the purpose of doing XYZ would Java or C# more efficient?" (with clear parameters defined as to what efficient means in your case) it _could_ constitute an appropriate question.

Comment: @A-Tech , well, other than the fact that i've asked this 9 years ago, your suggestion still doesn't answer my question i guess ?

Comment: @Noctis well So if asked differently as pointed out, otherwise any less formal programming forum I guess.

Answer (score 11):

The real value of a social network can be measured by the people that are inside it.

The SO gamification style attracts talents that want recognition. For many people, it's more relevant than LinkedIn.

See the answer above. The user earned more points from people supporting the answer than being chosen the best answer (not counting badges here).

To make SO work for discussions, it would be just a matter of removing the "right answer" and let people vote for the best opinion, roughly speaking.

I think SO should consider this idea, maybe in another Beta community.

Knowledge is not only answers.

Answer (score -3):

I think that, as already said, the base of Stack Overflow is to provide the best answer possible to a specific issued question. That means that the discussion part is done just by the users answering with multiple solutions, and voting for the best one. Even if point-to-point, this could be interpreted as a form of discussion about a topic.

Added to this mechanism then there are comments that can be posted under each of the solutions provided, so there's a way to discuss everything related to relative answer to the question. These comments threads often creates long discussion about how the answer could be edited, adding more information or providing a better way to do things.

Having said this, maybe a "discussion" section could be useful to some extent, but how Stack Overflow is set is not like a forum, so I don't think we will see this section anytime in the future.