# Opinion based questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

As important as it is to have a Q&A site where you ask how to do something and get a straight answer, there are times when what you really need is not how is something done, but what's a good way (or if possible, the best way) to do something, based on some other user experience. I'm talking questions like, "I know how to store data on a database, but I am not sure what design pattern to implement in this particular case".

In the previous example, due to software scalability, I would want an opinion from people who have already done something similar, about what pattern should I use and why. This question is indeed subjective and opinion-based, but it doesn't make it any less constructive, as software scalability is a pretty important part in the design process.

That being said, opinion based or subjective questions can be important as objective questions. Please, let us have a space for this type of questions.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion about "I need the best way questions" and "it has to be an opinionated question". Look at software recommendations (the new SE site). They have questions asking for "the best tool for the job", and they _find the best answer_. Sure, someone can have an opinion about which they like, but at the end of the day, the community works to find the one that works the best. That's the **answer**. And that's what we want. Answers.

Comment: We [tried that](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) already and it went badly. Why can't you ask for opinions on Quora or Slashdot or Reddit?

Comment: I just don't get why opinion based questions are taboo. Consider the example where I don't know which navigation would be the best for my Android app: tabs or nav drawer.  the answer IS opinion based, but not on "I like it better that way"  but on a real determinant as "do it with tabs because you are going to be presenting same data displayed in different ways".  See? this is an opinion with very good fundamentals

Comment: See also [The Story Behind Programmers Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/163250).

Comment: Out of two duplicate question links, one has already been deleted and the other is not clearly a duplicate.

Comment: There used to be all of these great LISTSERVs or IRC where you could have these wonderful debates.  But now everyone defaults to Stack Exchange, complains it won't allow for opinion, and then says, "What's IRC?"  Those were the days my friend.  Those were the days.

Comment: [You can ask such questions on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-SQL-Server-the-best-database-system?share=1)

Comment: Also see [Why doesn't Stack Overflow allow discussable questions or questions that requires opinions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252854/why-doesnt-stack-overflow-allow-discussable-questions-or-questions-that-require)

Comment: This is a great idea. Unfortunately, this question and the ones it links to are closed in such a circular fashion as to discourage and prevent answers which state it is a great idea, and why.

Comment: It's a type of lockout circle. They took the mutex and won't give it back, and now they're in an infinite loop just repeating that allowing questions and answers with opinions is bad. It's a deadlock.

Comment: Related (my question; part of this lockout circle): [Can we open up Stack Overflow to accept questions which are opinion-based? This induces a constructive answer of pros & cons & industry best practices](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403040/can-we-open-up-stack-overflow-to-accept-questions-which-are-opinion-based-this)

Comment: I don't know the statistics, but I suspect that there is a great number of opinion-based questions at Stack Overflow that have many views and up-votes, meaning that users and visitors ARE interested in such questions and don't consider them to be bad. Some of the answers of such questions are very complete and informative, aggregating many views on the topic, which is very useful. I, myself, have learned a lot from reading some of them, and think it is a bad thing that these questions are closed, preventing new contributions to be made. +1 for the OP suggestion.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Ok, so let's try to walk through why this is not so good of an idea.

Let's start with a very old opinion-based question, [What non-programming books should programmers read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210/what-non-programming-books-should-programmers-read)

Look how many answers there are. 316 of them! That's a lot. That's a lot even if you wanted to read all the posts. The problem is, none of these are *wrong*, but none of these are *right*. These are all people's opinions, and you can't tell someone that their opinion is wrong (except for me, I can say whatever I want). So what can we call "the answer". Which one should the OP choose?

Now, that is a more extreme example. Let's take something more recent. How about [this recent question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cWtX.png). The question boils down to about the same example question you had: "I have this code base, which has these vague requirements, and I need to do a task. What is the best way to approach the problem?"

As of this writing, it has 1 vote for "too broad" and 2 votes for "primarily opinion based". It's "too broad" because there are too many possible methods to attack the problem, and it's "primarily opinion based" because those solutions would be based on the person's opinion. Yes, maybe in a better question which had the specifications better defined you would have a narrower set of results, but really, in the end, most of these questions get opinionated answers. We close these questions to stop people from giving opinionated answers.

A bad question is ok; a bad answer is BAD. That really kills the site.

Another problem with these types of questions is that it's an excuse for the author to be lazy. The tool-tip for downvoting includes "does not show any research effort", and you will be hard-pressed to find a question like this actually showing any sort of research effort. You are wanting us to look up either a method or tool for you to use, instead of making the start yourself.

I always tell people to go to Google first. Say you want to find the best way to move data between your phone app and your desktop app. Well, do you know at least one method? Find one, look it up, research it, figure out if it will work for you or not. Then lookup another, and maybe a third. We want you to help yourself. Only you can find the best tool for your job, and spending the extra time researching yourself will save you, and us, a lot of time.

So your argument to that will be "well we could have one central location for these types of requests, saving internet readers a lot of time in research themselves". True, but this brings us back to the first example in my post: too many "answers", and none of them can be seen as correct or incorrect.

Bottom line: if we allowed opinionated questions, we would be flooded with opinionated answers, and voting would be nothing more than a straw-poll of "which do you like the most". A site reader would have to parse through so much more content to find what they were looking for, which is the **ANSWER** to the question.

Comment: how about tagging such questions and answers or editing questions before deleting? i know SO community does help LOTTTT... but simply closing questions seems stopping discussion to happen. May be new branch under stackoverflow to cater to some questions which may lead to opinion based answers cuz SO has huge valuable community and information on SO should not be only FAQ but idea based. point being some questions may lead to opinion baed answers n some to idea based/idea generating. opinion based vs idea based question... can we have something like this supported??

Comment: This inexorably leads to the question "is it possible to ask a question that does not lead to an opinionated answer?". The answer is no; it's impossible. All answers are based upon opinion regardless of the subject. Thus the reason why Stack Exchange needs to change their guidelines, because, by their chosen definition, every question ever asked qualifies as "opinionated".

Comment: @Krythic Is there an opinion about what the result of "1+ 1" is? In my opinion it's 2. Sure if you doubt about everything that is accepted as common knowledge there can only be opinions.

Comment: @trixn Technically, at the event horizon of a black hole and beyond, 1+1 could equal every number simultaneously. So no, asking what 1+1 is would still result in an opinionated answer.

Comment: @trixn Furthermore, math is entirely based upon perception and scale, we're taught 1+1 = 2, because that's what we as a society agrees that it should be. When in truth, an exact match of 1+1 is practically an impossibility on most universal scales. You hold up two apples and say "I have two apples", but that statement itself is a paradox because how do you define an apple? Is there a requirement for Mass? I doubt both apples will weigh the same, or even have the exact fructose makeup or number of seeds. The answer is subjective, because the question is invariably subjective.

Comment: @Krythic That's what i said. If you doubt about everything there can only be opinions. We could also all live inside the Matrix and this is not even a real platform. But what is the benefit of thinking like this? We wouldn't even have computers and be here to write this comments if every scientist doubted about the correctness of the natural constants. This platform considers "1 + 1" to have a definite answer and "What is the best framework for XY" to be opinion based. It think the difference is very clear.

Comment: @trixn Given a generic definition for "best", are you really trying to convey that at any given moment there is not a "best" framework for x constraints? I'm certain that all frameworks are not equal, and one would likely be "better" than another for x task. So it seems to me, that given an appropriate definition for "best", one could still yield a marginally adequate answer. This is, quite naturally the fundamental problem with Stackoverflow. Their definition for opinionated is intrinsically "opinionated".

Comment: Uh, you guys are getting a bit overzealous. Please make a new question or head to [chat] if you're going to keep going.

Comment: That's exactly the point. There is a publicly accepted generic definition for the result of a mathematical equation that's why it's not considered opinionated. But nobody will be able to give a similar definition for "best framework", that's why it is considered opinionated. @gunr2171 You're right. Last comment from me here.

Comment: I disagree and in my opinion the banning of opinion based topics decrease the usefulness of this site greatly

Comment: This is the most Stack Overflow comment thread ever.

Comment: To know whether an opinion based answer is good or bad, this is what votes are for. If the opinion based answer is generally not a good one, it will have a bad rating. And sometimes the solution is very hard to find on the internet or come up on your own. If you allow opinion based questions that would significantly simplify lives of developers.

Comment: And what if you need an opinion based answer quickly, and you don't have time to do a long research? Isn't it useful to have some platform when you can get recommendations from experts who know what they're talking about? I think you could figure it out how to make it work well.

Comment: Although your answer is correct, I hate the idea that we can not ask for opinions. Some times I get stuck and don't understand the correct approach. I can put what I've failed at trying, but that is too broad because I accomplished as much as I could in that route and it didn't do what I needed it to do. Asking for other approaches gets flagged as opinion based but that is exactly what I would need at that moment. Just someone to talk to about why they would or wouldn't attempt one way over another. There is huge value in that info regardless if there is little value in a site that houses it.

Comment: So, where do we ask such questions than?

Comment: @vanowm Seems like Quora really has this concept figured out, also Reddit has anything but a problem with opinionated answers...