# Can we open up Stack Overflow to accept questions which are opinion-based? This induces a constructive answer of pros & cons & industry best practices

Tags: discussion, questions, scope, opinion-based

Closing good questions which have useful answers and apply to many developers for being "opinion-based" or "too broad" is one of the huge problems I have with Stack Overflow in general. It **unnecessarily prevents developers from learning from each other in ways that are otherwise impossible--especially for isolated developers**.

Here's one potential example: "What are the pros and cons of Unity vs Unreal Engine?" Allowing this question to remain and be answered gleans expert knowledge from real, professional users of each and helps people make informed decisions. It helps the community immensely to gain these insights from real users! I've answered and asked many questions with some aspect of opinion in them, and I *want* the opinion-part included and answered, because it *helps* me and others and *combines experience*.

Many questions which are closed widely benefit the community. See this search result for Stack Overflow questions which are closed: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3A1.

1. The [very first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication) has 5426 upvotes with 12 answers, the highest of which has 3816 upvotes, yet it is closed for needing to be
   "more focused". I'm pretty sure a question with 5426 upvotes and and answer with 3816 is focused enough.
2. The [next one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background): 4513 upvotes on the question, 7177 on the main answer, yet it is apparently also not "focused" enough.
3. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189452/when-to-use-margin-vs-padding-in-css), closed for being "opinion-based" has 2407 upvotes on the question, with 1635 on the answer.
4. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices) is requesting information on industry "best practices", from fellow developers, yet it "needs to be more focused"--this is an alias for "closed because it contains opinions."

All of these questions are closed when their upvotes very clearly yell that they *do* greatly benefit the community, and thousands more which *could* greatly benefit the community are closed before they even get the chance to begin gaining traction.

#### I vote we allow "opinion-based" questions on the site which either:

1. expose constructive discussion on pros and cons of different techniques, as this helps us all as developers in our decision-making processes, OR:
2. expose industry best practices, as this helps us identify patterns which are more-widely-accepted, more-widely-understood by others, and more-likely to be successful, OR:
3. provides a useful list of tools or approaches to begin solving a problem, as this is immensely helpful as well

**I'd like to stop seeing good questions closed--especially those which are widely-upvoted and have a strong answer base, purely for being "opinion-based".**

Personally, I hypothesize that many people with closing power follow Stack Overflow's policy of closing opinion-based questions because they simply believe Stack Overflow got it right and they want to be helpful. The new generations of developers went to school (ALL of their college) *after Stack Overflow had already been founded and gained an industry-wide foothold as the place to ask software development questions.* This means that when this new generation got their jobs, they likely already knew that Stack Overflow was the industry standard, and believed that Stack Overflow is good, Stack Overflow does what should be done for sites like these because it is so successful, and Stack Overflow doesn't allow opinion-based questions, so that's how it should be. These new generations are trained from the beginning to see through a certain lens. Perhaps they learned to begin downvoting and closing questions which are "opinion-based" simply because that's what they see done all the time and that's what they see repeated they are "supposed" to do. They may not look as deeply as they should at questions and answers based on their merit, usefulness, correctness, and community contribution, and instead simply start scanning them to quickly identify if they might be "opinion-based". They then get a false sense of "helping" and accomplishment by closing these "opinion-based" questions. They think they are making the site "better" because this is what the main answerers want.

This is the status quo Stack Overflow has created. I challenge it because I think it is a mistake.

Comment: Related? [Why opinion-based questions cannot be answered or implemented here?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274762/2745495)

Comment: Related: yes; duplicate: no.

Comment: This sounds like a suggestion or a feature request, but you start it off with an assumption of how people think and what their mindsets are when they VTC questions as opinion-based. I don't know if you've got citations for that, but I think it would be better to focus on *why* these opinion-based questions adds value to the site or how this site loses value without them.

Comment: For a while I also thought the same: Opinion based questions have the potential to get more views and make $tackoverflow a thing. But then I realised that I, nor does anyone else wants to spend time answering a one sentence question that reads, "Should I use unity or unreal engine?".

Comment: @10Rep, that question should simply be answered as though it was asked: "What are the pros and cons of unity vs unreal engine?" Then it gleans expert knowledge from real, professional users of each and helps people make informed decisions. It helps the community immensely to gain these insights from real users! I've answered and asked many questions with some aspect of opinion in them, and I _want_ the opinion-part included and answered, because it _helps_ me and others and _combines experience_.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Yea, sure it helps people. But the thing is people need to answer it before it can do any help. And I just don't see anyone answering a one sentence question here. Plus, when I googled "unity vs unreal engine?", I get tons of youtube videos and blogs. Why do we need to get into that set of search results?

Comment: @10Rep, some things aren't so easily Googled. Here's a question I asked which was closed for being "opinion-based". I was _seeking industry experience_ from others. It certainly is not a 1-line question. Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52732931/is-it-bad-practice-to-specify-an-array-size-using-a-variable-instead-of-define. It even received 3 answers before being closed. It was an engaging question to those answerers.

Comment: @GabrielStaples I'm cooking up an answer in regards to your latest comment. You do have a good point.

Comment: “Many others just follow the lead and automatically learn to begin downvoting and closing questions which are "opinion-based" simply because that's what they are trained to do and told they are "supposed" to do.” - So everyone is just a lemming?  They cannot possibly believe that questions seeking our opinion isn’t helpful?

Comment: @SecurityHound of course.  Who would believe that trained, skilled and experienced developers, users with decades of testing and debugging, could possibly have minds of their own and make informed decisions?

Comment: I like the post but you'll get much disagreement with your hypothesis (it's easy to get wrong). Also, it's important to note that you (hopefully) are not generalizing opinion-based questions, but talk about these rare perls that sometimes are posted. I very rarely see questions like that, but when I do, they get the attention they deserve.

Comment: @MartinJames, many users with closing power have just a couple years of experience at most--and they literally went to school (ALL of their college), and got their jobs under the premise that Stack Overflow is the industry standard, Stack Overflow is good, Stack Overflow does what _should_ be done for sites like these because it is so successful, and Stack Overflow doesn't allow opinion-based questions, so that's how it _should_ be. You mock me, yet this is the new generation of developers. They/we aren't lemmings. They are just trained from the beginning to see through a certain lens.

Comment: @Gabriel - Except you indicated that’s exactly what we are, everyone is just following everyone’s lead, in closing questions.  That’s what a lemming is, they blindly follow the next person, over the wooden platform to the warp gate. I don’t need to discuss topics with people outside of my company, but if I am looking for a solution to the problem, I want the solution not an opinion

Comment: @GabrielStaples How do you know that? Many users with closing and moderating powers are actually people who went to college. Unless you provide stats I won't believe you.

Comment: @SecurityHound, you just affirmed one of my points when you said: "I don’t need to discuss topics with people outside of my company". Well, what of the microcompany, micro-startup, or lone developer who needs to glean the industry for best practices and has no "company" for peer review and to find "best practices"?

Comment: And plus, like you said, many of these questions you provide just won't be googled. In that case, they are pointless, and have no value.

Comment: @10Rep, you lost me: I said they went to college. They just began college after Stack Overflow was created is all I said, meaning Stack Overflow had influence on them from the beginning because it existed before they began college.

Comment: I don’t need to have that discussion at Stack Overflow.  It’s not a discussion forum.  What does college have to do with anything?  There are many developers who are relatively inexperienced, have no college degree, but have knowledge that far exceeds any college graduate.

Comment: Yes, SO is not the place to discuss stuff about a company or something.

Comment: @10Rep, that's not what we are talking about. We are talking about going to a peer _in your company_ to discuss pros and cons of something. I'm saying, "if you don't have a company with peers because you are alone, go to Stack Overflow to ask a question about best practices." Do research, write it out in a well-thought-out question, seek answers from Stack Overflow "peers" because you have no company peers.

Comment: @GabrielStaples That makes no sense to me. If you don't have a company, then go to SO and ask an opinion based question that will get closed because most of the community agrees that opinion based questions should be closed? Sure, you have no company peers, but that doesn't mean you should ask it here.

Comment: *"This exposes a constructive dialog of pros & cons & industry best practices."* Yeah, that's precisely the problem. It opens up a *dialog*. Stack Overflow doesn't do dialog. This is a Q&A site. If it can't be objectively answered, then it doesn't belong here. Also note that we tried this before, based on popular demand, creating a separate site for these types of questions. It didn't go well. Actually, it was a complete disaster. That site's scope has been changed drastically since then, which is the only reason it's still afloat.

Comment: _I challenge it because it's a mistake_. that is a good thing. Raising awareness of something and getting disagreed with on meta are good things and have happened to everyone.

Comment: @CodyGray, I didn't mean an actual back-and-forth conversation. I meant a monologue: where an answer lays out pros and cons and provides details--not a true back-and-forth dialog. I mean just a regular, good, well-thought-out answer. I've updated the question title.

Comment: Overall, I think this conversation has revealed that the people benefited by the closed answers aren't on the meta site. This is expected. I suspect they frequently are the weekly users not the hourly ones. I'm more of an hourly user. I should focus my energy elsewhere. I'll go back to [converting my bike tire](https://www.instructables.com/Tubeless-Bike-Tire-Conversion/) from having an inner tube to being tubeless now.

Comment: What do you see as the difference between a "weekly" user and an "hourly" user? Why do you think that I, or others, wouldn't benefit from these type of answers? There have been plenty of times when I've had and wanted to ask a question that I knew wouldn't be allowed on Stack Overflow. It's just that I have a good understanding of why the site has the rules that it does, based on experience of what works and what doesn't.

Comment: @CodyGray, `What do you see as the difference between a "weekly" user and an "hourly" user?` "Weekly" users come a few times a week to the site, seeking answers. They upvote helpful questions or answers, even when they are opinion-based. "Hourly" users are on the site sometimes non-stop. Many of them downvote opinion-based questions and seek to mark them as duplicate even when they are not. Experience tells me this is the case. I've watched many many of my questions or answers get downvoted or closed live in front of my eyes. Weekly users, by definition, wouldn't be sitting there ready.

Comment: I can guarantee you that nobody is "sitting there ready"... You're just underestimating the sheer scale at which Stack Overflow operates. *Someone* is always there; it's almost never the same someone. For example, you've never received more than ~5 votes from the same person (either up or down), and even that has only happened a couple of times. So, contrary to what your comment makes it sound like, it's not like there's a small cabal of users who are single-handedly downvoting and closing this type of content.

Comment: @CodyGray, on Stack Overflow that may be true. But, my experience is gleaned from the Stack Exchange sites as a whole. So, that's not quite true. On Arduino Stack Exchange the active user list is so small I can even poinpoint _who_ did it, by looking at activity timestamps. Paid Stack overflow employees once even had to get involved to help clear up some abuse of this. But, the Stack Overflow culture dominates the Stack Exchange sites, and justifications for things frequently point right back to this meta here, even from other Stack Exchange sites. So, the culture should be addressed here.

Comment: @CodyGray, having said that though, this question/concern is really addressed at the Stack Overflow community. That's where I spend the bulk of my time anyway.

Comment: This doesn't work in practice. I have two words to demonstrate the point: Editor war.

Comment: @CodyGray, you said: "For example, you've never received more than ~5 votes from the same person (either up or down), and even that has only happened a couple of times." Are you looking at actual stats to see this? If so, I believe that only users with >10,000 reputation can look at such stats, right? Once I hit 10,000 reputation, how do I search and see these stats?

Comment: @CodyGray, also, it's unfortunate that your comment above with 10 upvotes is based on a misunderstanding of what I said, and an incorrect word choice I used (I said "dialog" when what I meant was "well-thought-out, descriptive answer". I don't mean "discussion"). The crux of the problem I'm trying to bring up here isn't: let's allow opinion-based questions, it is: let's quit closing factually-based opinion-influenced questions which either have widely benefited the community (by counting the tens of thousands of upvotes they have), or which *might* do so if they just weren't closed instantly.

Comment: I see. Thanks for updating with examples. Based on those, it seems the "opinion" aspect is actually a red herring. The problem with those questions is neither that they are opinion-based nor that they invite discussion/dialog. The problem is simply that they are too broad to be conclusively answered in our format. If broken apart into smaller questions that asked about different aspects, I think they would be perfectly reasonable questions for Stack Overflow. But currently, as posed, they are *book topics*, not Q&A topics.

Answer (score 18):

Ultimately, in order for a question and answer format to work, questions [need to be able to be *answered*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/), not just discussed. That's the entire point of having a question and answer format.

That doesn't mean that all subjective questions are terrible and can't be asked. The linked article has some clear guidance on what we consider a constructive subjective question, but again, it must be possible to answer questions with facts and evidence (rather than just opinions and discussion).

Discussion forums may be interesting or entertaining for the participants, but if you're an outsider looking for specific information from the thread you usually have to wade through endless *me too!* comments and thread hijacking to find it.

With that said, note that Software Engineering SE does take somewhat more "subjective" questions than SO does, so you may want to check to see if your question is on-topic there.

Also, speculating on the motives of people who close questions is little more than an [ad hominem attack](https://fallacyinlogic.com/circumstantial-ad-hominem-definition-and-examples/); it [does not provide any relevant evidence in support of your conclusion](https://www.logicalfallacies.info/relevance/) even if true (which it isn't).

Comment: I feel you on the "forums" part. Thousands of "it didn't work" and "me too!".

Comment: @10Rep Me too!!

Comment: Opinion-based answers _can_ be fully written and answered. I've done it. Many have. They _can_ be answered. Tens of thousands of upvotes on [answers on closed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3A1) readily prove this point. I think what your argument _should say_ is simply that they can't be definitively stated to be the "right answer". Rather, they answer simply reveals tradeoffs and "industry best practices" or "industry common practices"/practices you are likely to see in industry.

Comment: If they can be answered they aren't opinion.

Comment: @user4581301 I'd like to point out that answering with an opinion doesn't make it an objective answer. A question of "Should I use X or Y" might be answered by somebody in quite an authoritative tone but still all stem from "You should choose X because I like it better".

Comment: @VLAZ I think we're making the same point.

Answer (score 11):

Well, such 'questions' fall into two categories:

1. Grossly underspecified requirements that, if any answer was possible, would be as close to guesses as anything else,(99.9%).
2. Requirement specs that ask, essentially, for a system design to be done for free, (0.1%).

So, no and no.

Answer (score 7):

You know, when I joined here and started curating this site, I saw the opinion based close reason and thought the same thing as you. At the time, I knew what Stack Exchange's existed for, which was to provide a useful repository of knowledge.

The thing is, nobody wants to answer a one sentence question that reads,

> Should I use Unreal Engine, or Unity?

The question asker didn't put much effort into their question, and now the answerer has to spend at least an hour cooking up a good list of reasons.

You may argue that a new contributor will answer, but their answer may go something like,

> uNitY bEcaUSe yOLo

or something similarly crappy, then it will be downvoted, and far from providing useful knowledge, it will simply litter the site. You see, questions have potential to be useful, but these questions need to get ***good answers***. That's the thing.

Also, you've mentioned [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52732931/is-it-bad-practice-to-specify-an-array-size-using-a-variable-instead-of-define), which you wrote that was closed as opinion based.

Right off the bat, I can tell that it is asking if [something] is good or bad practice. We don't encourage questions like these, because 99% of questions that relate to "good or bad practice" give such ***obscure*** cases. Plus, think about it. A lot of people view questions even after they are answered. Who will go looking for a question that reads, "Is [this] a good practice?"? Remember, all questions need to have value for future readers as well, not just the answerer.

In any case, your question has a net score of around 0, and you actually got an answer with a good net score! It contributed (somewhat) to the repository of knowledge we try to build.

So, to conclude, we don't want to allow opinion based questions, as there's just no scope on Stack Overflow. A lot of them will go unanswered, and without answers, questions don't contribute anything.

I go by [Makoto's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274766/12708583) <sub>which I read 2 mins ago</sub>. I realised that on a site like Stack Overflow, there's just no place for opinion based questions. Experts don't want to answer them, they can be crappy, etc.

Comment: I wonder how true this is: "A lot of them will go unanswered, and without answers, questions don't contribute anything." We don't _really_ know unless we let them go unanswered for...let's say, 1 year. That gives the Google bots the weeks or months they need to find it and make it searchable, plus regular users time to stumble into it and answer it.

Comment: @GabrielStaples As I and many others have said, experts don't want to answer one liner opinion based questions. You may argue that not all are one line, but I adress that in my answer. And as you say, if "regular users" stumble upon it, they may give one liner answers as well, which, again, we don't want at all.

Comment: My question isn't really about 1-liner questions _at all_. A good question shows research. It should be a 1-liner title, followed by research and thought, as my question is, or shorter of course, but along that vein. I don't want 1-liner questions left open either, I want _good_ questions left open. They will show some sort of thought and research.

Comment: "The thing is, nobody wants to answer a one sentence question that reads, [...]", you are simplifying this too much, this is 1. wrong and 2. not a real argument. "[...] the answerer has to spend at least an hour cooking up a good list of reasons.", there are tons of cases where simple question have extended answers. I think you are missing to actually address the problem that the OP is talking about.

Comment: @GabrielStaples I have adressed that in my answer.

Comment: @akuzminykh I have adressed the OP's example in my answer. The short answer is that nobody will go looking for a question that says, "is [this] a good practice?". It just goes against the goal, intent and style of SE.

Comment: @10Rep The OP is not talking about pure "is [this] a good practice?"-ish questions, but about ones that we can truly discuss and so on. You are redeucing the problem to bad examples that work for you as an argument but skip the actual point of the OP. "It just goes against the goal, intent and style of SE.", yes, but you know .. things can evolve .. and apparently SO was much more open-minded in this direction in the beginning. Now it's very strict and this is what the OP addresses. At least the way I'm understanding it.

Comment: @10Rep And by "discuss" I don't mean questions where any user will just drop their opinion based 2 cents. Just questions where someone can really write an extensive answer that requires the reader to think when they apply the suggestions on their specific case.

Comment: @akuzminykh Can you give an example? Regarding SO, the thing is people need to answer questions. If people don't want to answer and disagree, then we might as well close them. The thing is nobody will probably write an extensive answer and if they do, it probably won't get viewed. Like, where is the value in such questions?

Comment: Regarding SO: Things evolved, and, given the reception on this post, probably won't evolve backwards (maybe in a million years, but I'll be dead then :(

Comment: @10Rep, you're making huge assumptions here when you say: "The thing is nobody will probably write an extensive answer and if they do, it probably won't get viewed." I write HUGE answers regularly--I mean, like really thought-out, tested, meticulous, article-type answers. And, I'm not alone. And yeah, they get viewed too. Here's one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44034633/google-mock-can-i-call-expect-call-multiple-times-on-same-mock-object/60905880#60905880.

Comment: @GabrielStaples But you said it yourself in [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403040/can-we-open-up-stack-overflow-to-accept-questions-which-are-opinion-based-this/403042?noredirect=1#comment809520_403040). Somethings dont get googled. If they don't, then they have no value for us and we close them. Simple. And the example you refer to was asked waaaay back. Notice that it's closed because now, it won't get views and won't help anyone.

Comment: @10Rep, I do _not_ mean people don't Google them, I mean: _when people Google for them, adequate answers do not exist_. One observation I have made is crystal-clear to me: the internet is _far far FAR_ from complete. It has gaping holes. We can fill them.

Comment: @10Rep Yeah, you have a point there, this post here will most likely not start a revolution. I think the examples by the OP are working just fine to illustrate the problem. The problem with these is that they are pretty old ...

Comment: @akuzminykh Yes, it won't start a revolution, but that doesn't mean it's not worth anything. I learnt a few things just by writing this answer. And you've raised awareness about this, which is also important.