# How to approach a moderator who has closed my question because they think it is a matter of opinion, when I can show that it's about facts

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, closed-questions, recommendation-questions

I've just posted the question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64942033/is-there-any-free-software-for-converting-svg-css-animations-to-video-for-windo .

In it, I'm asking for software that:

- (1) converts SVG/CSS animations to video format;
- (2) is free;
- (3) runs on Windows;
- (4) delivers results compatible with YouTube;
- (5) can be run automatically without needing manual screen-capture;
- (6) is high quality, without jerkiness, strobing, or other problems.

As far as I can see, the first five are objectively verifiable by anyone. Delivers video format? Look at the output format. Is free? Try getting it without paying, and see whether that works. Runs on Windows? Try it. Delivers results compatible with YouTube? Try it and see. Can be run without manual intervention? Try it.

The only property that one might say is subjective rather than objective is number 6, quality. But I have normal vision through my specifications, and I know whether I think something is blurred or jerky. If I didn't, and if people didn't agree on the norms, opticians wouldn't be able to fit glasses. So quality is just about the same for everyone, and might as well be counted as objective.

The reason I say the above is that your moderator has closed my question on the grounds that it's not answerable with facts and citations. I don't see why, because the above shows that five of the qualities listed are factual, and the sixth is as close as makes no difference.

Moreover, similar questions have been asked before. Here are some:

- [Convert SVG animation to image sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58938653/convert-svg-animation-to-image-sequence) ;
- https://superuser.com/questions/434649/how-to-take-a-css-animation-from-a-browser-and-export-a-gif-of-it ;
- https://superuser.com/questions/48532/convert-animated-svg-to-movie ;
- [How to render a MP4 movie from HTML animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39087817/how-to-render-a-mp4-movie-from-html-animation) ;
- [Export svg animations to gif, webm or videos format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48197849/export-svg-animations-to-gif-webm-or-videos-format) ;
- [Convert SVG Animation to webm or mov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50436280/convert-svg-animation-to-webm-or-mov) .

If my question about how to convert SVG/CSS to video is to be banned, why were all these allowed to stay?

I am annoyed not only at the banning, but at the brusque, rude, abrasive, curt, slighting fashion in which it was done. I put a fair amount of work into my question, honouring the Stack Exchange maxim that one should ask the question as well as possible. So I understandably feel that this has been slighted, when many less-well-researched questions on the same topic are allowed through.

By the way, I just Googled "stack overflow not nice" and discovered that other people feel the same way, see the blog post at https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/ .

And the thread [Firing mods and forced relicensing: is Stack Exchange still interested in cooperating with the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper) , which mentions *The last weeks and days have seen some erratic behaviour by Stack Exchange Inc., such as likely illegal changes to the content license and the firing of an upstanding community moderator with no explanation except copy-pasted responses* made me ponder.

So I'd be very grateful if someone could explain

- (a) why were the other questions about SVG/CSS-to-video allowed to stay while mine wasn't?
- (b) Why doesn't Stack Overflow regard the attributes I'm asking about (video output, free, Windows, YouTube, automatic, not jerky, etc.) as factual?

Comment: Recommendations are explicitly off topic, per the help center. The close voters followed the guidance correctly.

Comment: It was NOT closed by a **moderator** but three normal users who used their close vote privilege to close what is **clearly** an off-topic request for a software recommendation. SO does not entertain these questions, although SoftwareRecommendations.SE *does*.

Comment: *"* ***We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for*** *books,* ***tools,*** *software libraries..."*

Comment: Different sites may have different rules. Some of the questions merely ask about how to do something and you'll notice at least one of them has a poor quality answer.

Comment: Just because other bad questions haven't been closed yet does not mean that your bad question should not be closed. And none of those other questions are asking for software. For the most part they *are* programming questions. Oh, and at least two of them aren't even on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can use a library, you just can't ask which one to use! If you have issues with using a library, that's a programming question...not a software recommendation question. You're fighting the wrong fight here.

Comment: and if you are using a library you need to tell us exactly what problem you're having using it. Just saying here's a library, use it to code a solution to my problem isn't going to fly either. That's what the last question you cite does and it has an answer. See the difference?

Comment: Oh, and as far as I know, you aren't **banned** from asking questions, you've had a single poor question validly closed. We've offered you a place to actually ask the question but you don't seem willing to accept our attempts to help you and maintain SO's integrity.

Comment: Yes, "sensible well-researched question" but **demonstrably and blatantly** not [**on topic.**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) You fell at the third hurdle.

Comment: [Voting is different on meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: Rudeness should never be tolerated, but nor should it be addressed directly. If you encounter it, best to flag it to a moderator and let them deal with it. They may not get to it right away, but will get to it eventually. Having said that, I don't see any rudeness directed towards you in your question (unless some comments have been deleted), but rather I see appropriate moderation. This moderation may be upsetting to you, but that is not evidence of rudeness. Rather, it is an unfortunate side effect of your learning site restrictions, restrictions that were given to you when you joined.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403044/758133

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels 'Rudeness should never be tolerated', well, unless is directed against curators.  Refusal to participate in the OP's system design choices is, supposedly, 'brusque, rude, abrasive, curt, slighting'.  I am hardly even surprised at this kind of abuse anymore:(

Comment: Never, ever compare your question to an old one. Old questions frequently slip past moderation, and should therefore not be used as an indicator to justify violating a rule.

Comment: Also.... 'well point 6 is subjective. But ..but not really in the end, so there's no subjectivity'. I mean if I ask an off topic question and say 'well this piece is off topic, but... But not really'. Come on :/.

Comment: @Patrice an example. "Red" is subjective. But the entire population agrees on when something is red, so in practice, the subjectivity doesn't matter.

Comment: @PhilvanKleur colour blind people might not agree. Also people who are able to see *more* colours might draw a distinction between "red" and, for example, "carmine". And speaking of colours and "everybody agreeing", I'd be remiss not to point out [the blue and black vs white and gold phenomena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dress).

Comment: Related: *[Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)*

Answer (score 38):

1. That question was not closed by a moderator. Moderators are indicated with diamonds after their user names.
2. Regardless of how objectively you establish the criteria, recommendation questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow. However, you might be able to ask over on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). Be sure to read [their Help Center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help) first, in order to ensure that your question is on-topic and will be well received there.
3. You haven't been "banned" from anything.
4. Closing a question is none of these things: "brusque, rude, abrasive, curt, slighting". The only thing rude that happened there were your comments, including this gem:

   > BLOODY HELL!!! I've done all this work, trying to provide a useful up-to-date list that readers can use as a starting point. AND YOU'VE CLOSED MY QUESTION WITHOUT EVEN ASKING.

   which a moderator had to delete. :-(

   Note that no one is expected to ask first before voting to close a question. [Questions are closed *first*, then we ask for clarification.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260263)
5. As for why some other questions about related topics might have been allowed to stay, I really can't say, unless I went through and looked at each individual question. Maybe they were posed differently from yours and therefore did not fall into any of [our prohibited categories](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Or, maybe they simply got missed. Stack Overflow is a large site, and sometimes off-topic questions fall through the cracks without getting closed. We don't promise to have *complete* coverage when it comes to moderation. Each question is evaluated independently; the existence of *other* off-topic questions doesn't justify your asking a new one.

Comment: "BLOODY HELL" isn't rude in England: it's the pre-emoji equivalent of a [bury-face-in-hands] [exasperation] [why is life treating me like this] emoji string, if there is such a thing. But thank you for explaining, and apologies if it offended anyone. I would have liked it, though, if someone had contacted me first and said "I think we have problems with your question: could we suspend it until we've discussed them". It's what I'd do if I were teaching and a similar situation arose. Analogous to Donald Norman's rule about user interfaces: always give sufficient feedback.

Comment: I will try Software Recommendations, but this leads to another problem in that I may have to split my list between off-the-shelf solutions and those that need some programming.It would, I think, be helpful if all the information could be kept in one place.

Comment: That's precisely what purpose that closure serves here. It puts a question that community members felt might not meet our standards into a temporary "hold" state, adding a big blue banner to the top that (so the idea goes) explains our concerns with the question and provides guidance on how to modify it. When questions are in this closed state, we don't allow answers to be posted. The reason for this is that any edits to revise the question to meet our guidelines would almost certainly invalidate any answers received in the meantime, which would be confusing and unfair to everyone.

Comment: The problem with that is that you don't give enough guidance on how to modify. Maybe it's impossible to without post-closure discussions like these comments, but I did try to see what you were getting at just after closure, and couldn't.

Comment: I may *bloody hell* hope it is rude in the rest of Great Britain....

Comment: No, not really. We're not a Christian country, and both words are Christian relics: "blood" as far as I know is the blood of Christ. It's about equivalent to "bugger", as in "WELL THAT BLOODY SVG CONVERTER HAS ONLY BLOODY GONE AND BUGGERED MY BLOODY WINDOWS REGISTRY". You'll even find it in Terry Pratchett.

Comment: @rene It's indeed not, some older generations may take a small amount of offence from  it, and parents might tell off young kids for saying it in the same way they'd tell them off for swearing, but other than that I'd be hard pushed to find anyone who found it rude

Comment: Um, it's not so much about the phrase "bloody hell" itself, but the fact that it was RENDERED IN ALL CAPS, WITH MULTIPLE EXCLAMATION MARKS!!1one

Comment: Oh I agree with that, it's brash and impolite and shouldn't have been added :p

Comment: Um yes, it adds to the effect. When I draw cartoons, I render the speech in all caps with multiple exclamation marks, too. It wouldn't work if you said it in lower case. Since we all need cheering up this year, have a look at https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/british-phrases-english-language-sayings-britain-england-uk-different-a8138046.html , if you're allowed to read it from where you are.

Comment: As an Englishman all my life, if you shouted bloody hell at me, I would have no doubt you are being rude @PhilvanKleur . I know some who don't think that the "C" word is rude, yet I think it's the most offensive word in our language; just because you don't think something is rude doesn't mean it isn't. But shouting at the users here is always going to come across as rude, as there's really no need for it.

Comment: Umm. .. may I, then, use such language when commenting on works requests and homework dumps from new accounts? (British citizen)

Comment: Once upon a time on the Internet I made a perfectly innocuous joke about monkeys and was horrified to later learn monkey is a horribly offensive slur when referring to the poster who had prompted the joke. Once I got over the shock of "What sort of sick <expletive deleted>s turned monkey into a slur?" I was more careful. The trick is to be careful, but not fearful. Decent people will let you know when you've stepped in it by mistake. The rest you'll have to deal with on a case-by-case basis..

Comment: So @Phil, someone closing your question is rude, but you basically screaming back at then isn't? That's..... Definitely not a 'treat others how you wanna be treated' PoV I feel

Comment: @Patrice read https://getpocket.com/explore/item/how-to-criticize-with-kindness .

Comment: @Martin James I've never commented on homework dumps online or works requests (not quite sure what you mean by that) online. But I have offline, and yes, that kind of exaggerated-to-the-point-of-parody speech is something I might use.

Comment: @PhilvanKleur Well you see, saying something in caps IS BLOODY HELL RUDE. You see what I mean? It sounds like you're shouting. And maybe in britain it's acceptable to say bloody hell (I say it all the time) but this is a _professional_ enviroment.

Answer (score 8):

The close reason tells you exactly what the problem is: this wasn't closed because it was opinion-based, it was closed because it was looking for a tool recommendation, which is off-topic here.

These used to be allowed on Stack Overflow, but they simply weren't working very well on the site. They drew lots of answers that were little more than links, spam, and opinionated answers.

On the plus side, you do seem to have constrained this well, and you show what possibilities you've already explored, which is more than most people do - that's important for this kind of question, because it tends to discourage (although not entirely prevent) the kind of garbage answers that people were providing before these questions got banned. It might work better at the Software Recommendations site, who does accept that kind of question.

Comment: I've moved it to Software Recommendations. However, that hits potential problems too. One of the tools I said I'd found is a website that does conversions, and I had another question closed (on Software Recommendations) because they don't allow you to ask about web-based tools. I just want to get the job done, and don't particularly care whether the tool is local or web-based (apart from upload and download speeds). So having to separate the two categories leads to what, as a programmer, I'd call a lack of modularity.

Comment: "The close reason tells you exactly what the problem is: this wasn't closed because it was opinion-based, it was closed because it was looking for a tool recommendation, which is off-topic here." Um, the notice I saw about the closure definitely told me that questions have to be fact-based. Why would the closer bother to mention that unless they're trying to imply that my question _wasn't_ fact based? Grice's Law.

Comment: One very important point. You say "These used to be allowed on Stack Overflow, but they simply weren't working very well on the site. They drew lots of answers that were little more than links, spam, and opinionated answers." Spam is bad, granted. But I'd rather have links and opinionated answers than not. They at least give starting points for a search. I have found useful software that way. That's one of the things I find most distressing about StackOverflow. People with power to delete answers or questions are too willing to remove info that, though poor, still helps. "Any port in a storm".

Comment: The text of the closure reason was recently changed, and I liked the old closure reason text better. That being said, most tool recommendation questions are *not* fact-based; yours is more constrained than most. Either way, I wouldn't get too hung up on the exact text of the closure message; it was closed for being about recommendations, which were found not to work well on the site for the reasons I mentioned.

Comment: Poor information can be a serious problem for the site because it makes it harder to find the good information. Do you remember having to wade through pages of *"me too!"* comments and thread hijacking on discussion forums just to find the one piece of information you actually needed? People generally visit SO because they're looking for specific, concrete information, not because they want some link with no context or some random person's unsubstantiated opinion.

Comment: @PhilvanKleur "*Um, the notice I saw about the closure definitely told me that questions have to be fact-based." ["We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more."](https://i.imgur.com/hJUhjyV.png).