# Tags don't wrap on questions for users without inline tag edit privilege

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

##### Update for currently supported browser versions

As of September 2021, this is still an issue in both Firefox (tested 93.0b2 on Windows 10 and 91.4.0 on Android 10), and on Edge 93.0.961.38.

You can identify potential candidates for displaying the bug with [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1457152/1789085/top-100-posts-by-tag-length), right now, the top spot is [Can I create a new Azure ML-workspace when creating an ACI from cloud shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62938710/can-i-create-a-new-azure-ml-workspace-when-creating-an-aci-from-cloud-shell). The result is the same viewing in both Edge and Firefox (screenshot from Edge 93):

[image]

Makyen's [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403057#comment866337_403057) indicates this is only a <10k issue, and has also been replicated in Chrome using an incognito tab:

> Users *with* the 10k "edit tags inline" privilege won't be able to duplicate this (i.e. the tags will wrap for them), unless the post has a pending edit. Users *without* the "edit tags inline" privilege, should be able to duplicate this issue (i.e. the tags won't wrap). The "edit tags inline" feature changes the HTML structure of that area of the page such that the tags are no longer directly contained in a flexbox which hasn't had wrapping explicitly enabled (flexboxes don't wrap unless they have `flex-wrap: wrap` (or similar), which the "normal" container for the tags doesn't have).

---

##### Original Post

When the screen is too narrow tags stay on one line, rather than wrapping as would be expected. This causes them to overlap with other content in the right side panel:

[image]

[image]

Using FF 83.0 (64-bit) on Windows 10 64-bit 19042.630:

This happens on both Stack Overflow Meta (the [question above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403055/a-late-answers-audit-where-the-reviewers-are-expected-to-notice-that-the-answer)) and on [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403053/how-to-approach-a-moderator-who-has-closed-my-question-because-they-think-it-is):

[image]

And on Stack Overflow Main ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64937469/too-many-open-files-when-using-multiprocessing-and-concurrent-futures)):

[image]

It can also be replicated using FF 82.1.3 on Android 10 (screen res: 2340 x 1080) (same questions, darker grey at sides of screenshots is area outside of screenshot, i.e., the edge of the screen):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also replicatable in Microsoft Edge (Version 87.0.664.41 (Official build) (64-bit)):

[image]

Comment: Looks like someone broke the Z order again...

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah, I put in 2 different screenshots so that was in there as well, although if the tags wrapped then that would be less important

Comment: What browser are you using? No repro on Firefox Nightly 85.0a1. Is this an issue you can reproduce elsewhere in the network or only on Stack Overflow or its Meta?

Comment: The tags are responsive on my browser.

Comment: @user4642212 Hopefully added enough example questions for you to replicate, original SS's were FF 83.0, added more for FF 82.1.3 on Android and for MS Edge

Comment: The problem is that the list of tabs **doesn't** wrap. To have horizontal scrolling with no good reason is a terrible solution

Comment: @Nick Are you experiencing this on newer browsers? Neither of these is on our list of [supported browsers](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/). We support FF 90 and 91 and Edge 92 and 93.

Comment: @Catija That is because this post is a year old Cat, but yes, I still experience it on Edge Version 93.0.961.38, also on FF 93.0b2 (don't have non-beta Firefox installed on PC), as well as FF 91.4.0 on Mobile (Android 10)

Comment: I'm using Chrome and both of these questions wrap properly. Mach closed a question as a duplicate of this one and the [tags in that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69100999/how-can-i-implement-bottom-sheet-with-bottombar-in-jetpack-compose) do *not* wrap for me... which is a bit of a head-scratcher.

Comment: @Catija Here's a screenshot from Edge 93 for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4uxA.png. Unfortunately of the posts linked here, 2 have been deleted and I can't see, the remaining one however: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMeyz.png. Issue arises either from narrow screen or extremely long tags. In FF (again, FF 93, so not yet supported): https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAPv5.png

Comment: Would you mind adding an update section with the info you're mentioning here? When this gets looked at it'd be helpful if the newer info was in the question. Depending on the timing, the newer versions may not be current any more but having an update that it's still going on would be helpful. :)

Comment: Can you try this post @Catija: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62938710/can-i-create-a-new-azure-ml-workspace-when-creating-an-aci-from-cloud-shell (quick SEDE query suggests its got the longest tags on the site)

Comment: That one works fine for me in Chrome. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvHfb.png

Comment: Interesting, that one doesn't work on edge, regardless of screen width it always intrudes on the right hand pane

Comment: Note: Users *with* the 10k "edit tags inline" privilege won't be able to duplicate this (i.e. the tags will wrap for them), unless the post has a pending edit. Users *without* the "edit tags inline" privilege, should be able to duplicate this issue (i.e. the tags won't wrap). The "edit tags inline" feature changes the HTML structure of that area of the page such that the tags are no longer directly contained in a flexbox  which hasn't had wrapping explicitly enabled (flexboxes don't wrap unless they have `flex-wrap: wrap` (or similar), which the "normal" container for the tags doesn't have).

Comment: @Makyen That would certainly explain Cat being unable to reproduce the issue

Comment: Yep. When I view it in incognito mode, I see the bug as you do, even in Chrome. So this seems to be what Makyen is saying, not a browser-related bug. Thanks so much for catching that, @Makyen!