# I do not believe I was asking a question that could not be answered with facts and citations

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, closed-questions

You have closed my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77932777/style-conventions-for-const-enums.

But it is perfectly possible answer the question with facts and citations. For example, what does Microsoft recommend? What does Google? It was quite clear that this was the point of the post, I even gave examples that had been seen in the various style guides I'd read.

It was wrong to close this question - and you allowed somebody to not answer it, which when I called that out you then retaliated by closing my post. This is why people don't ask questions on this site, because you don't want them.

You will still not re-open it - you are not applying your OWN rules fairly.

Examples of existing posts:

[What is the naming convention in Python for variables and functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159720/what-is-the-naming-convention-in-python-for-variables-and-functions?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C132.9755)

[Go naming conventions for const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688906/go-naming-conventions-for-const?r=SearchResults&s=9%7C87.1329)

I changed it in good faith, you still have said no. It is quite clear you just make it up as you go along.

Comment: so, either you're asking for 3rd party resources, or you're asking for opinions. Which one best fits your scenario? Sounds like the former, which is another close reason.

Comment: I am asking for what is RECOMMENDED stylistically, to use for enums. For example, what do the large companies recommend? I am not asking people to opine on what they like to use, I'd like to know what the recommendations are, e.g. by the people that make the language. There are no questions like this on SO, it would have been a very useful post that could have had many resources but as usual you've closed it.

Comment: Right, but, how can someone provide that without providing 3rd party resources? Do you expect people to just objectively "know" what an entire company with tens of thousands of employees recommends? If there's a company-introduced recommendation, it's a 3rd party resource, you can just go read it,

Comment: You are asking for recommendations of corporations *and each and every reader* ("Are there conventions [...] that you, yourself enforce in your projects?"). The latter will necessarily be their own, personal opinion. How does that not make the question opinion-based?

Comment: Then remove the bit about "that you enforce" and just stick to what the big companies use, what does the language recommend? Post the resources, there's no opinion there. That could have been done without closing down the whole question - but you only did that because somebody didn't even answer it and I called them out for it.

Comment: @KevinB I could not FIND any resources, hence why I asked the question. If I knew the answer, why would I ask? Do you just not ask questions, is that how SO works now?

Comment: "Then remove the bit about "that you enforce" and just stick to what the big companies use, what does the language recommend?" Well yes, if you want to then please do so. You can just [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77932777/edit) the question yourself.

Comment: I already did that. I am not sure why you had to close the question at all.

Comment: And look, the downvotes have arrived, honestly do you ever consider that the way you approach this site really puts a lot of people off using it?

Comment: "I am not sure why you had to close the question at all." Because it was off-topic as per [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I am not sure why that is surprising.

Comment: @Gigabit have you considered the way *you* approached this site puts people off from helping you?

Comment: Or you could just ask somebody to change it and they could change it. I find it VERY convenient that you closed it as soon as I called out a user for going completely off topic. Why are you not taking action against them @MisterMiyagi?

Comment: @VLAZ it's not me that made a huge post that said SO is known for being abrasive, condescending and rude and needs to change how it is as so many people are put off posting here. The attitude of posters here clearly hasn't changed one bit - my colleagues were ABSOLUTELY right that asking questions is a complete waste of time.

Comment: @Gigabit Your comments make it appear that you have not considered that you might be wrong. Please carefully consider the feedback you're getting and that you might be wrong.

Comment: Even if I could (I cannot, and I'm not sure why you think otherwise) I see no reason to. There was no misconduct at all. The question was off-topic, so it was closed and the banner informed you why. Now that you edited it it is no longer off-topic due to this reason and being reopened.

Comment: The only thing I did wrong was to add three extra words to my post. I am speaking to a culture which comes through in every moderation decision that is made. Now I've admitted where I was wrong, how about you think about how you and co moderate posts to attract people to actually want to post? Or do you just not care?

Comment: @Gigabit "I am always right, anybody who ever does anything I don't like is wrong" is what you are projecting here, Do you really think that makes you sound reasonable?

Comment: You could just try addressing the points I've actually made @VLAZ. Why close questions rather than just asking the people to change them? Why are people who post off topic comments not penalised but those who ask questions, are? Why has the attitude of this site not changed one bit despite it supposedly making an effort to change?

Comment: No, I won't. You are *very clearly* not interested in the answers to those questions. If you were, there is an entire help centre and plenty of discussion what SO is or isn't about. You've ignored this. I posit you have asked your questions just to nitpick the answers to try and achieve some sort of perceived victory. You've already engaged with closed-minded and logically fallacious claims here. Declared yourself correct using circular reasoning. I have little reason to expect you are seeking honest engagement here. If that were the case, you'd have already questioned said circular reasoning.

Comment: "Now I've admitted where I was wrong, how about you think about how you and co moderate posts to attract people to actually want to post? Or do you just not care?" I do think about that, regularly. And then someone comes along and just smears everyone because they haven't read and understood the most basic rules of the site. Like here just explaining what is going on without having partaken in any negative action is enough to get a mouthful...

Comment: SO has a problem with questions being downvoted and closed for spurious reasons. Wasn't me who said that, SO did. So why are you still continuing to not make any changes to actually want to improve things, you are just doubling down. There's a reason people don't want to post here, as I said, do you just not care?

Comment: Your rant here is your opinion, it’s not shared by other people. “Do you just not care?” is a silly question to ask. Of course people who don’t agree that you’re right don’t care that what you want to happen isn’t happening. Why would they?

Comment: You're saying people aren't put off posting here and that questions aren't closed for spurious reasons and downvoted for no reason? Even when SO themselves have said this is the case? I can now see why it hasn't improved.

Comment: No one here has categorically ruled out moderation mistakes. But such mistakes happening doesn't mean any and all moderation must cease, especially when it is clearly following the rules.

Comment: If you want to know a specific company's guidelines, there should be a clear reason why you cannot just ask **that company**. If you are asking generally about companies, then you are leaving it up to the opinions of Stack Overflow users to choose the companies to look up and report, *and it becomes just as subjective* as it would be if you asked users for their own opinions. In fact, people answering such a question will be *motivated* to look up companies whose practices support their own personal opinions - which is **part of why** we have the policy against "seeking resources" questions.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel then why are there plenty of questions on StackOverflow about style conventions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159720/what-is-the-naming-convention-in-python-for-variables-and-functions?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C132.9755 - why can't they just ask the people that make Python?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688906/go-naming-conventions-for-const?r=SearchResults&s=9%7C87.1329 - why can't they just ask Go? You're not fairly applying the moderating criteria.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37532530/typescript-getter-setter-convention?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C61.1165 - why is this allowed? Why can't they just ask Microsoft? I would like to appeal this decision to the moderating team because it's quite clear you're not applying the rules fairly.

Comment: I have opened a new post to appeal this ludicrous decision.

Comment: **Please read**: [Should I flag old questions that ought to be closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250060), [Opinion based questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255468) [Can we open up Stack Overflow to accept questions which are opinion-based? This induces a constructive answer of pros & cons & industry best practices](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403040) etc. The topic of "but there are old opinion-based questions around!" comes up constantly.

Comment: Finding that someone else's question wasn't closed, when policy indicates it should have been, **does not** mean your question closure was unjust. It means you should help keep the site clean by voting or flagging to close questions that don't meet the [standards clearly set out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/) on Meta, [in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) etc.

Comment: And do not repost on Meta just because you don't like the answer you got the first time. This is not making an appeal; it is arguing and complaining.

Comment: @rene I'd prefer not to see this specific question generalized. While a question about "Are coding style convention questions off-topic?" could be useful, if it's not a duplicate, there's enough contention surrounding this specific question, and the other questions asked today, such that if the question "Are coding style convention questions off-topic?" is going to be asked, I rather see a new question posted that doesn't retain the context of this specific question.

Comment: "Why close questions rather than just asking the people to change them?" You can learn this by reading existing Meta posts. It is a fundamental part of how the site works. (It also **does not prevent** people from changing them, and in fact **is a way of** asking for the change: changing it allows for **fixing the reason it was closed**, which can convince others to reopen it.)

Comment: @Makyen I wasn't aware we had a "do not improve contentious posts" rule but I'll take your opinion on this to heart going forward.

Comment: @rene I'd argue that merely changing the title and leaving the ranty body as it is isn't really an improvement in the first place.

Comment: @F1Krazy you have to start somewhere ...  baby steps ... learning curve ...

Comment: @rene I didn't mean the question shouldn't be improved. I meant I'd prefer it not be *generalized*. Your title is what I'd expect on something like a FAQ entry or a general discussion of the underlying issue, which then becomes a reference Q&A to be referred back to many times. The use of that title made me concerned that transitioning this question into something like those might be your intent. I don't feel that this question is an appropriate candidate for that process. If a reference question on the underlying topic is desired, I'd prefer a new question without this one's context/baggage.

Comment: @Gigabit "Why close questions rather than just asking the people to change them?" -- Why ban users rather than just asking them to stop acting out? Because a lot of time, the request is about as futile as asking a rock to move itself. And here we don't have to go very far looking for an example.

Comment: @Gigabit - "Why close questions rather than just asking the people to change them?" - It takes numerous questions that are not well received to be question banned.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not dealing with the original revision. Currently the question reads (which was deleted after this revision):

> What are the conventions recommended for typing consts (that act like enums) in TypeScript? Are there conventions enforced by the large companies or that Microsoft (the makers of TypeScript), have produced?

I believe questions about official conventions, or even officially recommended best practices, are on-topic. If the last line could be rephrased as

> What are <sup><sup>[Credit:Philipxy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427975/i-do-not-believe-i-was-asking-a-question-with-answers-that-could-not-be-answered/427999#comment986225_428000)</sup></sup> the conventions that Microsoft (the makers of TypeScript) have regarding this?

I believe that it would be certainly on-topic—questions about official documentation/styles, especially in TypeScript, would certainly be on-topic.

If we take the exact quote per se,

> Are there conventions enforced by the large companies or that Microsoft (the makers of TypeScript), have produced?

"Conventions enforced by Large companies" would certainly be opinion based. *Large* by whose standards? Why should we care about conventions enforced by them? But it is followed by a "or"—"that Microsoft (the makers of TypeScript), have produced?" The last one would be a question about official language spec. If there are two questions and one is off-topic, salvaging questions is a better way to handle that, rather than nuking everything from orbit.

As a corollary, *if* all the body of the question asks about one thing, but if there's a single line that asks about  something off-topic, better to remove that line rather than nuking the post for that one line. Salvage, as much as possible, rather than nuke should be the default policy. I do not agree with the current deletion.

Comment: "Are there"--bad. "What are"--good.