# Migrating SO-related questions closed as "pertains only to a specific site" on Meta.SE automatically back to Meta.SO

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, meta

I've just noticed [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167516/148833) on Meta.SE. It is tagged with `stackoverflow` and, obviously, it was on Meta.SO before the Meta split.

It has now been closed as off-topic on Meta.SE because it "*pertains only to a specific site*". Indeed it is site-specific, but it was asked in the right place at the time.

Wouldn't it make sense to migrate questions closed for this reason back to Meta.SO automatically, when they have originated from Meta.SO?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332974/4356188

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatically? No. There are a lot of questions on MSE that get closed for that reason, a lot of them long since resolved or no longer useful in any way. We certainly don't want to be migrating all that stuff back here. All it would do is clog up our Meta site with stuff that doesn't need our attention.

The migration of content back here has pretty much ended. If you do encounter something still on MSE that has a lot of value and *absolutely needs to be* migrated here, you'd have to flag it. For that particular question, I'm betting it would get declined.

[As Tim Post explains](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237100/will-the-remaining-questions-here-that-belong-on-mso-eventually-get-migrated/237116#237116):

> If it's *important*, and *still relevant* - then go ahead and write a new post on MSO. Put the reinvigorated passion into the discussion that it deserves, if it's important to you. Let the conversation play out again, but this time, *just for Stack Overflow*.

Comment: Can you not migrate them back without resetting their timestamps (to prevent them from showing up in the active list here)? I can't really see the point of leaving these questions closed *there*, thereby clogging up MSE.

Comment: @Bruno Migration does preserve the timestamps, but it's *also* an event that bumps it into the active list. But my concern wasn't really over them appearing in he active list. Migrating them here serves no purpose if they're already resolved. You're just adding questions for the sake of adding questions.

Comment: (I was suggesting finding a way to prevent them from bumping up in the active list.) In this case keeping them on MSE serves no purpose at all. Having them here serves the purpose of knowing what these past discussions were and how they've been resolved. (A sort of "building a repository of knowledge" about SO, even if some of it is outdated.)

Comment: Just for the background, I was mainly asking this because [this MSO question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252854/372643) was closed as a duplicate of [this deleted MSO question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252444/372643), which was linking to [this MSE question closed as site-specific](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167516/148833). Overall, quite an unsatisfactory path... You've reopened [this MSO question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252854/372643) now anyway. Still, I'm not convinced leaving the old stuff closed on MSE is a nice "gift" there.