# Why aren't all the questions on Meta.SO that pertain to multiple or all Stack Exchange sites migrated to MSE?

Tags: discussion, questions, meta, migration

I've seen many questions here on Meta.SO that could really apply to multiple or all Stack Exchange sites. Why aren't all of those questions migrated to Meta.SE? **(reasons other than the 60-day limit)**

Example of such a question: [add inbox notification for rejected edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298822/add-inbox-notification-for-rejected-edits?rq=1)

Comment: Are there still questions that fall under the 60-day limit that would justify migrating, is the real question.

Comment: This question should be migrated to Meta.SE because it pertains to all child meta sites.

Comment: @narawagames So why did you ask here then? Looks you just created an _infinite loop_.

Comment: Two things:  I'm not sure this warrants migration since it still pertains to MSE with respect to MSO, and also, it's unclear what you're really getting at since you haven't provided us any concrete examples of, "This question would *absolutely* belong on MSE as opposed to here."

Comment: Well, so that the question can get an *answer* that's tailored to SO.  Second guessing that this is not what the OP intended is not useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're asking the wrong question. Why should they be? We monitor all Meta sites for bug reports and feature requests, and there's no real reason to ask it on the main Meta site over a per-site Meta unless you explicitly want or need feedback from a wider variety of users across the network. Most people don't.

Moving it also limits its visibility to members *on that site* - feedback which may be more relevant to your request considering it was created in the context of that particular site. A migrated question is no longer eligible for the Hot Meta Posts section of the bulletin (because it's locked), and gets automatically deleted after 30 days, completely disappearing from the origin site. This is particularly problematic for support requests because the answer will disappear and exist on a different site, so users will just keep asking the same thing over and over because they can't find the existing questions that keep getting migrated to the main Meta.

Comment: To add to this, most of the time we migrate question from a child meta to MSE when it would benefit from a more broad discussion. Outside of that... there isn't much point to it. Re-asking on MSE is even worse since that fragments any discussion *and* potentially increases the work required to respond to, say, a bug report since now it's in multiple places.

Comment: "there's no real reason to ask it on the main Meta site over a per-site Meta unless you explicitly want or need feedback from a wider variety of users across the network" and even then, most are SO users.